Flutter failed to build ios app, unsupported option -G for target
I just updated my macOS to sequoia 15 and subsequently updated Xcode to 16.0. My flutter application was working just before my update but now running on my ios simulator, i get the following error:
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:11CEC440-4A5D-41D2-8FCA-9D2D245137D7, OS:18.0,
    name:iPhone 16 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:11CEC440-4A5D-41D2-8FCA-9D2D245137D7, OS:18.0,
    name:iPhone 16 }
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/tr/yb7b1tfj3674zn3rlk57mf6r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.COssk3/flutt
        er_ios_build_temp_dirTmt5Jl/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    clang: error: unsupported option '-G' for target
    'x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator'
    clang: error: unsupported option '-G' for target
    'x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator'
    clang: error: unsupported option '-G' for target
    'x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator'

If i run some of my other applications, there arent any errors and it runs successfully. It's only this app that has this error :/
The initial error I got was IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET not within acceptable version range of 12.0-18.09 but i fixed that with:
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15.0'

But now im getting the error above. I also didn't have to define this config.buildsettings with my other projects. They all have similar packages and have a specified ios version of 12.0.
I've also done the following:

flutter pub cache clean

flutter pub cache repair

flutter pub get

pod install


We had this error as well. The fix was two pronged. We had to add the following to our Podfile:
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == ‘BoringSSL-GRPC’
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings[‘COMPILER_FLAGS’]
          flags = file.settings[‘COMPILER_FLAGS’].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == ‘-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS’ }
          file.settings[‘COMPILER_FLAGS’] = flags.join(' ’)
        end
      end
    end

// ... your other Podfile settings here 

And secondly, in XCode select the Runner under targets, go to Build Settings, and search for "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules". In the Runner Target column, set it to 'yes'. Once you make this change you should see this line
CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES;

added to your ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file for however many targets your project builds to.

This works! Thanks

Worked for me also, thanks
(Not sure why we have to do this on certain projects but this solution works).

We encountered a similar error, and the solution involved two key steps. First, we needed to modify our Podfile by adding the following code:
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
          target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
            if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
              flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
              flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-Wgcc-warn-inhibit-all-warnings' }
              file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end

Secondly, in Xcode, select the your App target, navigate to Build Settings, and search for "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules." Set this option to 'Yes' under the App Target column. After making this adjustment, you should see the following line added to your App.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file, reflecting the change for each target your project builds:

this issue is not specific to Flutter only this is related to Xcode16. specially when you come from Xcode 15 to Xcode 16

Steps to Resolve the Issue:
step-1: Update cocoa pods-
sudo gem install cocoapods

pod repo update

Step-2 :
cd ios
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod cache clean --all

Step-3: then add those codes in Podfile file.
just replace this
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

with this
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

step-4:
do that
 flutter clean
    flutter pub get 
    cd ios
    pod repo update
    pod install

After that, build clean and then build again in Xcode.
step-5:

Select a runner from TARGETS

On the row select Build Settings and search for and set it to yes
ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES



just replace this
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

with this
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

